# R testthat: How to ignore classes in expected result (error "Classes differ")

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

How can I ignore the class attribute in `testthat` unit tests?

Currently the tests fail because of different classes:

```
library(testthat)

testthat("drinks taste good", {

  values <- c("COFFEE", "TEA", "SOFT DRINK")

  expected.values <- values

  class(values) <- "myclass"

  expect_equal(values, expected.values, check.attributes = FALSE)
  # Error: `values` not equal to `expected.values`.
  # target is myclass, current is character

  # funny: Try it with switched variables causes a different error message
  expect_equal(expected.values, values, check.attributes = FALSE)
  # Error: `expected.values` not equal to `values`.
  # Classes differ: character vs myclass  
})
```

Edit 1: `expect_equivalent(values, expected.values)` doesn't work neither since it ignores the attributes but **not** the class (via `check.attributes = FALSE`):

```
Error: `values` not equivalent to `expected.values`.
target is myclass, current is character
```

Comment: Well you could use unclass. Or you add the correct class to the expected values.

Comment: Good question. If you use `as.character(values)` the tests run through. But to me it seems, that `check.attributes` argument does not what I would have expected.

Comment: @Roland `unclass` seems to be the easiest way. If you post this as answer I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't ignore class, so have to deal with that difference in your code.
As suggested in the comments, `unclass()` is sufficient in this case.

As for toggling attirbutes, class is checked independent of attributes, so you can't toggle it off with the `check.attributes` argument.

Also, the funny behavior when switching the order of the values comes from internal method dispatch: it's using `compare.default` when the `myclass` value is first and `compare.character` when the character vector is first.